# Do the Watcher fights affect the game at all?

Tags: el-shaddai

I'm in chapter 9 in El Shaddai: Ascension of the Metatron, and so far I've come across several miniboss type fights. These have been most often with Watcher Azazel, but sometimes with Watcher Ezekiel or Watcher Sariel.

I've lost most of them, except one with Watcher Azazel. However, they don't seem to have any effect on the plot of the game. When I lose, the Watchers respond with a comment about how I'm not strong enough, and the one time I won, Azazel merely responded with the equivalent of "Next time, Gadget, *next time!*"

Will winning or losing these fights have any effect on the plot or further gameplay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Watcher you fight in El Shaddai has 6 life bars. Every time that you beat a Watcher, they lose a life bar. If you win a Watcher fight, you'll notice that in subsequent encounters with them, a piece of their armor will be missing.

Ultimately, you will have a final battle with every Watcher that you must win. They will have as many life bars left as you've left them with. So if you've beaten them every time, they will be much easier.

Since an actual life bar indicator is absent from the game, your only real indication is the armor they have left (2 arms, 2 legs, chest, and face).

Take Sariel for an example, if you beat him the first time, the armor on his right leg will be broken/missing.

If you defeat him in [chapter 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjK-N0jusUk#t=10m02s), in [chapter 4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67ek7c1lis0#t=14s) you see a piece of this leg armor broken off.

But if you defeated him the previous 2 times, you will notice 2 pieces of his leg armor are [broken/missing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mwb8bNBMZL0#t=2m50).

For more details see [this discussion](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/996488-el-shaddai-ascension-of-the-metatron/60159216) on GameFAQs

Comment: So the outcome of the random fights actually affects the final boss battles? Do you have any sources for your information, as this is the first time I've heard this at all.

Comment: Since an actual life bar indicator is absent from the game, your only real indication is the armor they have left (2 arms, 2 leg, chest, and face). Take Sariel for an example, if you beat him the first time, the padding of his right leg will be broken/missing. If you defeat him in chapter 3: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjK-N0jusUk#t=10m02s , in chapter 4: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67ek7c1lis0#t=14s you see that piece broken off. But if you defeated him the previous 2 times you will notice 2 pieces of his leg armor is broken/missing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mwb8bNBMZL0#t=2m50s

Comment: Also see: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/996488-el-shaddai-ascension-of-the-metatron/60159216

Comment: Thanks! Can you add that explanation and video links to your main answer? It'll flesh it out a bit more and make it easier for future visitors to see. :)